# Why am I experiencing memory leaks in C (codeblocks)

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to print a 2d array, but I keep experiencing a memory leak that leads to first array in ppInt to give an addresses.
0: => [ 1906000 0 1906032 ]
But the rest of the array prints normal
1: => [ 40 50 ]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "e1_1.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

void Print_2Darray(int **ppInt){
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        printf("%d: => [ ",i);
        for(int j = 0; j< e1_1_size[i]; j++){
            printf("%d ", ppInt[i][j]);
        }
        printf("]\n" );
    }
}

int main() {
int** ppInt = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int)*INPUTSIZE);
    int start = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < INPUTSIZE; i++){
        ppInt[i] =(int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*e1_1_size[i]);
        for(int j = 0; j< e1_1_size[i]; j++){
            ppInt[i][j]= e1_1_input[start];
            start++;
        }

    }
Print_2Darray(ppInt);
    for (int i = 0; i < INPUTSIZE; i++){
        free(ppInt[i]);
    }
    free(ppInt);
}
```

error:
Process returned -1073740940 (0xC0000374)   execution time : 22.043 s

Comment: Include all of the definitions to form a [mcve].

Comment: I guess `INPUTSIZE` is 10 and defined in `e1_1.h`? Anyway, when you alloc for `int** ppInt`, you need `sizeof(int *) * INPUTSIZE` bytes -- the members of that dynamic array are pointers to `int`.